# Detect Index Coalesce

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, index

Is there a way to know if a `COALESCE` has been done on an index?  Doing one doesn't seem to update the `CREATED`, `LAST_DDL_TIME`, or `LAST_ANALYZED` attributes.

Note:  I am not referring to the `COALESCE` that returns the first non-null expr in the expression list, but the one that is used to [make free space in a block contiguous](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16508/logical.htm#CNCPT89012) like this:

```
ALTER INDEX [Index Name] COALESCE;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not completely clear what your after with your question. I assume you want to know if and importantly when an `alter index .. coalesce` was performed.

I think without (an in other answers already mentioned auditing setup) it is impossible to get such a date (although I would want to know if someone knows better).

That said, the effects of an `alter index coalesce` can be made visible with a `analyze index .. compute statistics`.

```
create table ix_test (
  a number
);

create unique index ix_test_ix on ix_test(a);

insert into ix_test 
select
  rownum 
from
  dba_objects, dba_objects, dba_objects
where
  rownum < 1e7;

commit;
```

Now that the table is filled, the index is analyzed and some index related values extracted:

```
analyze index ix_test_ix compute statistics;

select
  LEAF_BLOCKS,
  AVG_LEAF_BLOCKS_PER_KEY,
  CLUSTERING_FACTOR,
  SAMPLE_SIZE
from
  user_indexes
where 
  index_name = 'IX_TEST_IX';

LEAF_BLOCKS AVG_LEAF_BLOCKS_PER_KEY CLUSTERING_FACTOR SAMPLE_SIZE
----------- ----------------------- ----------------- -----------
          2                   19875                 1       15152
```

All but one row deleted and index analyzed (again):

```
delete from ix_test where a != 500000;
analyze index ix_test_ix compute statistics;
```

The query above returns the same values.

Coalescing the index:

```
alter index ix_test_ix coalesce;
analyze index ix_test_ix compute statistics;
```

The query above now returns

```
LEAF_BLOCKS AVG_LEAF_BLOCKS_PER_KEY CLUSTERING_FACTOR SAMPLE_SIZE
----------- ----------------------- ----------------- -----------
          1                       1                 1           1
```

So, there is a possibility to find out if there was a coalescing done, but it's not straight forward and probably useless, depending on your context.

Comment: The date would have been nice, but I think gathering evidence that a Coalesce has occurred is about the best we can do.  The solution I came up with is similar to yours, but from a slightly different angle, so I will post it separately.

Answer (score 2):

If you do a coalesce, isn't it worth gathering indexes at the same time.
But have you tried AUDIT

http://psoug.org/reference/auditing.html

Comment: Index operations for CREATE INDEX, ALTER INDEX, ANALYZE INDEX, and
DROP INDEX can be audited.  Does a Coalesce invoke one of these and if so is there a way to distinguish it from the named audit action?

Answer (score 2):

The solution I used doesn't give me exactly what I wanted, but did provide evidence that a `COALESCE` had been done.  I did an `ANALYZE` and looked at the number of leaf blocks in `USER_INDEXES`.  Then I did an `Gather_Index_Stats` and compared the number of leaf blocks.  If the `ANALYZE` was showing more leaf blocks than `Gather_Index_Stats` then a `COALESCE` could consolidate free space and therefore was likely not done.  If the numbers were the same then either no `COALESCE` was necessary, or it was done.  Here is my test script.

```
--Setup Table and Index.
create table t1 as select mod(rownum,5) myrow from dual connect by rownum<=1500000;
create index t1i1 on t1 (myrow);
delete from t1 where myrow IN (1,2,3);
commit;

--Analyze table and examine leaf blocks.
analyze table t1 compute statistics;
select leaf_blocks from user_indexes where index_name='T1I1';
--Gather Stats and examine leaf blocks.
execute sys.dbms_stats.Gather_Index_Stats(ownname=>user,indname=>'T1I1');
select leaf_blocks from user_indexes where index_name='T1I1';

--If there is a difference in the number of leaf blocks shown between running 
--these then a coalesce would be able to coalesce something.

alter index t1i1 coalesce;

--Analyze table and examine leaf blocks.
analyze table t1 compute statistics;
select leaf_blocks from user_indexes where index_name='T1I1';
--Gather Stats and examine leaf blocks.
execute sys.dbms_stats.Gather_Index_Stats(ownname=>user,indname=>'T1I1');
select leaf_blocks from user_indexes where index_name='T1I1';
```